# Visual foxpro 9: dump a Microsoft SQL Server varbinary field to a file

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro, varbinary

I have a program written in VF9 that uses a MS Sql 2008 Database.

Here the problem:

I have a SQL Table which have some files in a varbinary format. Where can I find a function that dump those fields to files in the local machine of the user that execute the program?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) should be able to do it for you.

Comment: I've found something on the net. Now I can transform the files from varbinary to file and viceversa directly from VFP 9 . Thanks anyway.